# what does -1 indicate in wx.ListCtrl in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

can anyone help me out knowing what does -1 indicate in following line of code?

```
self.lst2 = wx.ListCtrl(self.right_panel, -1, style=wx.LC_LIST)
```

Also, what does ('') indicate in following line of code?

```
self.lst1.InsertItem(0, '')
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem on-topic for Stack Overflow, please see [ask], and the [help/on-topic].

Comment: -1 = `wx.ID_ANY` = `wx.NewIdRef()` = I don't care what ID you give the object, just make sure it has one. `self.lst1.InsertItem(0, '')` - Insert a blank in the first position of the listctrl.

Answer (score 2):

@Bhagya,

For the first question:

In that code snippet `-1` is the ID of the control.

You can assign your own ID but -1 means that you let wxPython assign the ID for you.

For the second question:

It means that you are inserting empty string into the control.

See [documentation](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.ListCtrl.html?highlight=listctrl#wx.ListCtrl) for more info.